# WINAPI - Empty a file?

Tags: c++, c, file, winapi

I want to empty a file and i got 2 ways :

1) Using CreateFile function with dwCreationDisposition = TRUNCATE_EXISTING !

2) Opening the file ,setting the file pointer to the beginning of the file with SetFilePointerEx and then calling SetEndOfFile !

Is there any difference and which one should i use ?

Comment: How about third way: `ofstream x("C:\\file.txt", ios_base::trunc);` ?

Comment: @MM. `ofstream`s lack a lot of functionality you get with `CreateFile` (like `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` or `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`). In contrast to `CreateFile`, `ofstream` reports errors through exceptions. This is neither better nor worse, but certainly different.

Comment: @IInspectable: The main reason to choose this way is to write portable codes (However the OP certainly talks about Windows).

Comment: @MM. I don't mind portability. Aiming for portability is often a Good Thing. However, when dealing with files/file systems, it usually isn't. Your alternative solution has no support for UNICODE file names, for example. This is a **real** deal braker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, both of these will achieve the same thing, and you would have to do a lot of "emptying" of files to be able to tell much difference in performannce - if files are large, freeing the no longer used blocks from the file allocation will be the main time taken anyway.

Of course, if you want more portable code, using `ofstream of("myfile.ext");` will also achieve this, as will `FILE *f = fopen("myfile.ext", "w");` (along with a few variations on the same theme).

There is very little difference between these variants in general, it's mostly a case of what makes most sense for the code you are currently working on. In other words, "what are you going to do next with the now empty file", and what kind of "handle" you may need for it.

Comment: Thanks ! thats the answer i was looking for !

Comment: @HMVC - The courteous thing to do now would be to accept the answer.

Comment: This answer did not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

> Using CreateFile function with `dwCreationDisposition = TRUNCATE_EXISTING` !

- This will open an existing file and discard the existing content, making file size 0.
- This method will fail if the file does not exist already.
- This can be understood as deleting the existing file and creating a fresh one, though it may not be technically correct.

> Opening the file and setting the file pointer to the beginning of the file with `SetFilePointerEx` and then calling `SetEndOfFile` !

- Open the file and keep the content of the file.
- This method will work irrespective of if the file is existing or not.
  Whether the file is already existing or not is completely left to `dwCreationDisposition` flag.
- Let's assume you open a file with following content:
  `0123456789`
  and write `zxc`, this is how file will now look like:
  `zxc3456789`

I strongly believe that they should allow combinations of `TRUNCATE_EXISTING` and `OPEN_ALWAYS` to tackle the specified case better.

Comment: I wonder how this answers "which to use" better than my answer?